# Replace UR battery by IMR with lower mAh

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-operated, diy, battery-chemistry

I am replacing a shaver’s battery, a Braun Silk Epil 5.

It uses a Li-Ion battery manufactured by Sanyo for Braun.
According to my research it must be a UR Battery like the [UR18500L](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/910771/PanasonicBattery/UR18500L/1) :

```
Size : 18500
Volts: 3.7V
Capacity : 1300mAh/4.8Wh
```

My question is pretty simple (and maybe dumb), the UR Batteries are pretty expressive.
Is it possible to replace it by an IMR Battery that has the same voltage but less mAh (Usually used for e-cigs)?

If it is, what would be the consequences ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other battery on the IMR website that can fit in terms of dimensions, would be the 16340 Lithium-Ion cell. Though this battery would have only mostly 600-700mAh. Which means you get only half the original runtime.

https://www.imrbatteries.com/imren-16340-700mah-button-top-battery/